# Problemas en mysql workbench"Error Code: 1005.(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este problema en una base de datos para un proyecto final escolar

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `gymn-os`.`maestros` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Aquí dejo el script de la base de datos espero puedan ayudarme la verdad no encuentro nada gracias

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Gymn-os
-- ----------------------------------------------------- DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `Gymn-os` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Gymn-os
-- ----------------------------------------------------- CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Gymn-os` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ; USE `Gymn-os` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Persona`
-- ----------------------------------------------------- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Persona` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persona` (
    `id_persona` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `apeido_paterno` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `apeido_materno` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `sexo` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `telefono` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `fecha_nacimiento` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_persona`) )  ENGINE=INNODB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pago`
-- ----------------------------------------------------- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pago` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pago` (
    `id_pago` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pago` INT NOT NULL,
    `fecha_pago` DATE NOT NULL,
    `descuento` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_pago`) )  ENGINE=INNODB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Gymn-os`.`Atletas`
-- ----------------------------------------------------- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Gymn-os`.`Atletas` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Gymn-os`.`Atletas` (
    `matricula` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nivel` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `disciplina` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `pago` INT NOT NULL,
    `persona` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tutor` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `contacto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`matricula`),
    INDEX `pago_idx` (`pago` ASC),
    INDEX `pers_idx` (`persona` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `pago` FOREIGN KEY (`pago`)
        REFERENCES `Gymn-os`.`pago` (`id_pago`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pers` FOREIGN KEY (`persona`)
        REFERENCES `Gymn-os`.`Persona` (`id_persona`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE )  ENGINE=INNODB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Gymn-os`.`Maestros`
-- ----------------------------------------------------- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Gymn-os`.`Maestros` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Gymn-os`.`Maestros` (
    `id_maestro` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `especialidad` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
    `experiencia` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
    `persona` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_maestro`),
    INDEX `persio_idx` (`persona` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `persio` FOREIGN KEY (`persona`)
        REFERENCES `Gymn-os`.`Persona` (`id_persona`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE )  ENGINE=INNODB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `usuarios`
-- ----------------------------------------------------- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
    `id_usuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `contra` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `persona` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`),
    INDEX `persona_idx` (`persona` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `persona` FOREIGN KEY (`persona`)
        REFERENCES `Persona` (`id_persona`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )  ENGINE=INNODB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: El error salta solo al querer generar la tabla [Gymn-os ]. [Maestros]!?

Comment: Salta con  [Gymn-os ]. [Maestros] y  [Gymn-os ]. [Usuarios] tambien con las ultimas 2 tablas esta mi problema

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la creación de la tabla [Gymn-os]. [Maestros] y se debe a que tu Constraint apunta a [Gymn-os].[Persona] cuando no existe dicha tabla con se esquema.

```
...
CONSTRAINT `persio` FOREIGN KEY (`persona`) 
REFERENCES `Persona` (`id_persona`)
...
```

Este error tambien te va a saltar al tratar de generar la tabla de [Gymn-os].[Atletas]. La que esta correcta es la creación  de la tabla Usuarios. Saludos!

**Edicion:**
Cambia los Set Null por Cascade como tienes en Gymn-os.Atletas.

Comment: La tabla atletas me la genera muy bien con registros y todo el único problema que tengo son en mi tabla Maestros y Usuarios

Comment: Intentaste haciendo el cambio del esquema!?

Comment: Que clase de cambio podría hacer? la verdad tengo todo el dia con esto y no se me ocurre nada si te refieres a editar la base de datos el problema es que tiene que ser esa como esta.

Comment: No, me refiero a mi respuesta en concreto, cambia a donde apunta el constraint de tu tabla Gymn-os.Maestro x el que te di en la respuesta. Pruebalo haber que tal.

Comment: Si ya lo cambie y lo ejecute sigue saliendo el mismo error en la constraint

Comment: Mm veo un patron, en los ON DELETE, cuando es atletas tienes CASCADE y en los otros tienes SET NULL. por que!?

Comment: ya lo cambie...si era ese el problema el SET NULL la idea de eso era que al borrar un registro se quedaran los otros registros sin borrar pero parece que eso es lo que causa los conflictos a puse todo en cascada y funciono muchas gracias

Comment: Edite la respuesta, te invito a que des por cerrada la pregunta marcando como correcta mi resouesta. Saludos y Gracias.